# Creating Complex Automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I am trying to use the automapper to map my Database table output to my class object. But the table has 3 rows that are all belong to single employee data which needs to be assigned to a single class object. How we can we create mapper ? Is it possible to create mapper with this table data ?

```
How can I write Autommapper  to populate the class EmployeeDetails

public  class EmployeeDetails
    {
        public string EmpNo { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Address Address { get; set; }
        public List<Phone> Phone { get; set; }
    }
  public class Address
    {
        public string Address_1 { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
    }
public class Phone
    {
        public string PhoneType { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNo { get; set; }

    }

Datatype    EmpNo   Name    Address_1   City        PhoneType   PhoneNo
Name        1234    Test    Test addr   Testcity    Null         Null
Phone       1234    Null    Null        Null        Mobile       123456
Phone       1234    Null    Null        Null        Work         789546

public IEnumerable< EmployeeDetails > GetEmployeeDetails()
        {
            return ExecuteEmpReader< EmployeeDetails>().ToList();
        }
private IEnumerable<T> ExecuteEmpReader <T>()
        { 
 DataTable dt=new Datatable(); 
//Assume the dt will be loaded as per the above table.
foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
   {
              yield return _mapper.Map<T>(item)
    }
}
```

Comment: it's possible, we ask that you first try and then ask for help.

Comment: From my experience, don't use automapper for complex maps.

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe there is a way to do what you want using solely Automapper. Specifically because of the merging of rows into one. This link shows how you can at least unflatten your object to your desired object structure, but then you would need to write the logic to merge the employees addresses and phone numbers yourself.

http://martinburrows.net/blog/2016/01/18/automatic-unflattening-with-automapper

On the contrary to make your resulting code easier to maintain in future. I would recommend creating some views of your Employee Object, one for Employee, one for Address, and one for Phone. Then you can use EF to map your views straight to your objects.